# Why is Selenium webdriver is not opening webpage?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browserstack, remotewebdriver

Hi i am trying to connect to remote webdriver on browserstack using Selenium but whenever the page loads in Chrome and Firefox i get a security message (see images below).

my URL is starting with https:// (when i manually open the browser i have to accept the certificates and continue before the webpage loads)

i have added this line to my code but it does not seem to make any difference:

```
 capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
 capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_NETWORK_CONNECTION, "true");
 capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
```

**NOTE:** This issue only occurs then the tests are run on the GoCD pipeline. when running on intellij it all works fine

error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//transport....
```

in chrome i see this:
[image]

and in firefox i get a similar message:
[image]

Comment: You may need to enable Local Testing. [Please find the documentation here](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#setting-local-tunnel)

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan i already have it enabled but still getting the error:  capability.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");

Comment: are you setting up the tunnel by using BrowserstackLocal?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding something as below and test:

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
 options.addArguments("--test-type");
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-gpu");
  chromeOptions.AddArguments("window-size=1980,1080");
  Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: I am doubtful if this will make any difference on security certificates. Can you back this up with detailed description about its dynamics?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem for anyones future reference.

This is because DNS requests were not forwarded for our host name on GocD.